# Online file converter via java

Tags: java

Is there a way to use Zoho's [file converter](https://viewer.zoho.com/converter) from Java to convert files? Thought about using [Watij](http://watij.com/webspec-api/) to post the form but not sure how to save the converted file.

Comment: You would definitely need to find a site which supplies a user API.  Zoho likely does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask Zoho if they have an API for this. What you want to do is probably not even legal.